# How to remove doctest flag when readthedocs build?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I've published my Python package and hosted the documentation on readthedocs.

I want to know how to remove doctest flags (e.g. `doctest: +ELLIPSIS`) from the documentation:

https://camphr.readthedocs.io/en/doc-doctest/

When I built the document in my local machine (`make html`), the flags was properly removed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/55052869/407651

Comment: @mzjn Thanks, but I want to know how to remove the flag in readthedocs hosting.
I tried the configs in that post but the flags still remains.

Comment: Is it possible to force readthedocs to use Sphinx 2.2.0 or later? I don't know any other way.

Comment: Thanks, I did it! Override the `sphinx` with `docs/requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Read-the-docs installs `sphinx<2` by default, which has a bug for `doctest` flag (please see the @mzjn comment).
Thus I prepared [readthedocs.yml](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html):

```
...
python:
  install:
    - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
```

and prepared `docs/requirements.txt` as follows:

```
sphinx>=2.2
```

Now readthedocs installs `sphinx>=2.2` and everything works well.